# Set the number of digits in describe() function of Hmisc package

Tags: r, hmisc

I try to set the number of digits when exporting in latex the result of describe() function.

MWE:

```
require("Hmisc")
dat <- rnorm(1000,mean = 0, sd = 1)
latex(describe(dat, digits=2))
```

produces the following output:

[image]

The `digits` argument does not seem to have any effect: nor the means values, nor the min/max values have the number of digits modified. Any idea to set the number of digits?

Comment: Can you be a little more specific, what is your question?

Comment: I want to display a limited number of digits wether in the low/high values or in the statistics (mean, quantiles, etc)

Comment: Your question seems very similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31712030/control-digits-printed-by-hmisclatex-on-a-psych-object  Does the answer for that one help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `digits` argument of `describes` is used to set `options(digits = digits)`.
 That is, `digits` specifies the **minimum number of significant digits** to be printed (see `?options`).
We start considering a vector of random numbers with `mean=5`, `sd=1`, and set `digits=2`.

```
library(Hmisc)
oldopt <- options("digits")
set.seed(1)
dat <- rnorm(1000, mean = 5, sd = 1)
dgts <- 2
dscr <- describe(dat, digits=dgts)
options(digits = dgts)
outltx <- latex(dscr, file="describe.tex")
dvips(outltx)
options(digits = oldopt$digits)
```

The output is:

[image]

Here the minimum number of significant digits is 2: one digit before and one after the decimal point (for example, the 95th percentile is 6.7).

Now we consider a vector of random numbers with `mean=0`, `sd=0.01`, and set `digits=2`.

```
oldopt <- options("digits")
set.seed(1)
dat <- rnorm(1000, mean = 0, sd = 0.01)
dgts <- 2
dscr <- describe(dat, digits=dgts)
options(digits = dgts)
outltx <- latex(dscr, file="describe.tex")
dvips(outltx)
options(digits = oldopt$digits)
```

[image]

Again, the minimum number of significant digits is 2; The median (`.50`), for example, is `-0.00035`, that is, it has 2 significant digits (`3` and `5`).

Comment: Ok, thx. Is there a way to do the same for the lowest/highest values ?

Comment: Exactly what I expected ! Thx